# How can I attach a custom built antenna to the NodeMCU (ESP-12E)

Tags: pcb, antenna, esp8266, pcb-antenna, nodemcu

Is there any possibility I can disable/remove the PCB antenna and replace it with a custom one, like a directional helical antenna? Can I just solder it on? I am an absolute beginner and have no real idea of how this works.

[image: My NodeMCU with the PCB antenna to the right]

Comment: maybe, but you have to know how to choose coax and attach ext antenna  https://www.instructables.com/id/Easy-to-Build-WIFI-24GHz-Yagi-Antenna/  I might choose rigid copper coax or semi-rigid  This one becomes very directional

Comment: Use something like Wemos D1 Mini Pro or ESP-07

Answer (score 2):

You could try but that  what involves cutting the old  pub antenna trace and soldering onto the ground and the existing trace. It may not work well.

A better choice is to get a esp module with an external antenna connector like a u.fl connector. A wemos d1 mini pro or a clone is compatible with the nodemcu and includes more features for cheap.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good answer, is there a reason it wasn't accepted?

Comment: @tgrrr some people never come back to the site once they asked their question. Maybe they found an answer somewhere else. It happens :)